# Django dropdown menu not working with tag 'load bootstrap3'

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am creating a website with django and I have a dropdown menu like this:

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">{{ user.username }}</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left">
    <li><a href="{% url 'users:profile' user.username %}">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Requests</a></li>
    <li><a href="{% url 'booking:cars' %}">Your cars</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Your reservations</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

If I go to a page that contains this piece of code:

```
{% load bootstrap3 %} 
{% bootstrap_javascript jquery='full' %}
```

The dropdown menu is not working, but if I remove the 2 lines above the dropdown menu works fine.

Knowing that I have to keep this 2 lines, how I am doing to solve this problem

Comment: Have you another import js and css codes?Perhaps the other js and css codes dominate bootstrap codes.

Comment: you need to import css and js file in sequence and don't forgot to import popper and jquery

Comment: @kamilyrb I have in the main page `page.html` load static tag and link like this one: `<link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">` but I don't have another tag `load bootstrap3` or `bootstrap_javascript`

Comment: @lalit-vasoya can you explain more and gives more details please ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to follow the sequence first `bootstrap.css` file second `jquery.js` then `popper.js` and then `boostrap.js` don't forgot to link `popper.js` this file are use for the open model

- boostrap.css using link tag
- jquery.js using script tag
- popper.js using script tag
- bootsrap.js using script tag

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/popper.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
</head>
```

> i give `CDN` link put in your code other wise download those file and link them,i gave you the above stuff follow those sequence & don't forgot `proper.js` or `jquery.js`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

- if this work then make right answer if don't work please give the console error that show you in your browser,

Comment: i give my answer check it

Comment: I am using bootstrap 3 and when I downloaded bootstrap I don't have the file `popper.js`, I think this is in bootstrap 4. And I think the scripts should be loaded at the bottom of the page not on the `head` so the pages load faster

Comment: if you load your script at bottom please make sure you need to write open model script after this it is right you write this